# a G-linear map between two representations

Tags: representation-theory

I am struggling with this exercise in Fulton & Harris book:

[image]

Part b) asks to find a G-linear map between these two representations if I am understanding correctly (terrible choice of words in this book), we can use either the first description or the second since we showed they are equivalent, but I am thinking it is the second description that we should use.

I tried to find a map $\theta: G\rightarrow G$ for which $T(\alpha)=\alpha \circ \theta$ works but it seems like no such $\theta$ is convenient ( for example $g\mapsto g_1gg_2$ ), then what other linear maps I should try ?

We want $T(\alpha) (h)= T(g^{-1}.\alpha) (hg) $ for all $h\in G$ where $T(\alpha)=\beta\in R$ is a complex valued map on $G$

Comment: $\theta$ should be the described map from the (complex) vector space generated by $(e_x)_{x\in G}$ to the space of complex valued functions on $G$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, are you using the first description? because my R is the space of complex valued functions on G

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, my comment was rather relevant for part (a). For (b) you need $\theta$ from and to the space of functions over $G$ satisfying $(\theta(\alpha))(hg)=\theta(g\mapsto \alpha(g^{-1}h))$. Verify what does it mean when $\alpha$ is the characteristic function of an element $x\in G$.

Comment: your statement is equivalent to $T(\alpha) (h)= T(g^{-1}.\alpha) (hg) $ still no clue even when I tried to characteristic functions; in general we need: $T(\delta_x)(hg)= T(\delta_{gx})(h)$ if $\delta_x $ is your characteristic function

Comment: Ahh.. I understand your notation now. The bijection we're looking for would be $T$ and you wanted it in a special form utilizing a $\theta:G\to G$. Actually it might work. Have you tried $\theta=g\mapsto g^{-1}$?

Comment: I am starting to think it doesn't work unless the group is abelian. Otherwise we can't compare the left action to the right action.

Comment: $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ was my first try but didn't work, notice how $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is an automorphism only if G is abelian.

Comment: That's correct, however here it's not required to be an automorphism. Any function is equivariant if satisfies the identity in question.

Comment: I did a terrible mistake, thanks for giving this the time.

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt was fine. Choose $\theta=g\mapsto g^{-1}$ and thus $T(\alpha)=x\mapsto \alpha(x^{-1})$.

We have
$$T(g^{-1}\cdot\alpha)(hg)=(g^{-1}\cdot\alpha)(g^{-1}h^{-1})=
\alpha(g\ g^{-1}h^{-1})=\alpha(h^{-1})=T(\alpha)(h)\,.$$